# No attribute 'get_default_graph'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a python code that goes as:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
....
gc.collect()
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(32,input_shape = (6,),activation = 'relu'))
...
```

But its giving me an error in line `model=Sequential()`. It is:

`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'get_default_graph'`

Or in the complete form:

```
File "neuralnetwork.py", line 38, in <module> model = Sequential()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/sequential.py", line 87, in __init__
super(Sequential, self).__init__(name=name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line 96, in __init__
self._init_subclassed_network(**kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line 294, in _init_subclassed_network
self._base_init(name=name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line 109, in _base_init
name = prefix + '_' + str(K.get_uid(prefix))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 74, in get_uid
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'get_default_graph'
```

I do know about neural nets, their working and all. I've implemented one from scratch. But I'm using tensorflow for the first time, and have no clue what this error possibly means. Please help me solve this. Thanks!

Comment: Are you mixing Keras and pure Tensorflow? The default graph is the one used by default. It may have been changed/erased by other lines higher in your code?

Comment: what is your tensorflow version (`print(tf.__version__)`)?

Comment: @SimonCaby I don't have much idea about it. Started using tensorflow today only. Sorry about that...

Comment: @Vlad `2.0.0-alpha0`

Comment: @SimonCaby I can upload the whole code till the error occurs if you want?

Comment: By default it’s eager execution in tf2 which doesn’t have graphs. Use older version of tf or use tf.keras

Comment: @Vlad ok, I'll try and let you know!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using tensorflow 2.0 you should use the keras API within tensorflow. Change the import statements to:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
....
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(32,input_shape = (6,),activation = 'relu'))
...
```